# Convert to high quality only if video is available in this quality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pandastream

In a few words my problem would be described like this:
**Do not convert in hd if I upload video from old mobile.** Right now when admin uploads a file, panda will convert it into all formats available in **Encoding profiles** tab, makes no sense to convert a video in HD quality and serve it as HD when this video is actually in a lower quality.

**What I did so far** - looked in the docs that says nothing about this problem, or at least I couldn't find it. I can't even be sure how to formulate the question in search engines. Except this I couldn't do too much.

Ideas, links would be very helpful. Thank you.

---

**Vote to close?**

> This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope
>   defined in the help center

- Sorry but, why SO keeps tags to **pandastream** in this case? Isn't this so that guys from pandastream could easily track bugs and/or missing documentation so they can fix bugs and/or update the docs? Eventually if they have a solution this would help other devs too.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all profiles all applied, but it is possible to select which ones should be used when sending a video file through API.
There's a parameter called `profiles` for that, it takes a comma separated string with names of profiles. Example (in Ruby):

```
upload = Panda.post('/videos/upload.json', {
            file_name: upload_payload['filename'],
            file_size: upload_payload['filesize'],
            profiles: "profile1, profile2",
          })
```

Another solution would be to create two separate clouds in Panda, with different sets of encoding profiles.